# How to cut a part of string with japan character in PHP?

Tags: php, substr

I have a string as: `$fullname = 'ワタナベサン';`

And some line code for cut a part of string with condition:

```
if (strlen ( $fullname ) >= 14)
    $this->FullName = substr ( $fullname, 0, 10 ) . '...';
else
    $this->FullName = $fullname;
```

But the result appears as wrong string as: `'ワタナ�...'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`substr`, and all other core PHP string functions, are not **multibyte aware** and cannot treat multibyte strings correctly. They only work correctly on ASCII strings or other single-byte encodings. To manipulate multibyte strings correctly, in most cases you need to use the equivalent functions in the [MB extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php).

See [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) for more information. Welcome to the rabbit hole of character encodings; you have a lot to learn. :o)

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use the multi-byte versions of the string functions when working with Japanese characters. Use [mb_substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php) instead of substr and [mb_strlen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php) instead of strlen.